# Is there an easy way to add multiple resources to a Win32/C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, chromium-embedded

Is there a way easily add multiple files/resources to an existing Win32/C++ project. I can currently add one resource at a time. Maybe there's a script out there I can use?

Thanks:)

Comment: Open the .rc in text editor and cut and paste the resources you want. The format is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple solutions

1. Open each resource file in Visual Studio. You can use Copy&Paste, Drag&Drop
2. Use a text editor and merge the files. In this case you have to take care about the different Ids in the header.
3. Just use a central rc file and use #include to merge all files into one. To document this you may rename your rc files into the type rci.

Except method 1. You may have problem with duplicate resource ids. There is a resource renumber tool somewhere  in the web that may help here.

Comment: Does method 1 involve doing it one at a time?

Comment: You can open as much RC files as you want in one session.